page unresponsive after implementing socket.io features
So I am new to vite react and sockets, and I seem to have run into a problem after putting sockets in my code. upon implementation, the page has now become unresponsive. these are the files I modified for socket implementation:
socket.js:
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: ["http://localhost:3000/"],
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("A user connected", socket.id);

    // socket.on() is used to listen to the events, and can be used both on client and server side
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("A user disconnected", socket.id);
    })
})

export {app, io, server}

server.js:
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

import connectToMongoDB from "./db/connectToMongoDB.js";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.routes.js";
import messageRoutes from "./routes/message.routes.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.routes.js";
import { app, server } from "./socket/socket.js";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

dotenv.config();

app.use(express.json()); // to parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads (from req.body)
app.use(cookieParser()); // to parse the incoming cookies from req.cookies

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/messages", messageRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);

// app.get("/", (req, res) => {
//     // root route http://localhost:5000/
//     res.send("Hello World");
// })



server.listen(PORT, () => {
    connectToMongoDB();
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

SocketContext.jsx:
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuthContext } from "./AuthContext";
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export const SocketContext = createContext();

export const SocketContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
    const [onlineUsers, setOnlineUsers] = useState([]);
    const {authUser} = useAuthContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (authUser) {
            const socket = io("http://localhost:5000/");

            setSocket(socket);

            return () => socket.close();
        }   else {
            if (socket) {
                socket.close();
                setSocket(null);
            }
        }
    }, []);


    return <SocketContextProvider value = {{socket, onlineUsers}}>{children}</SocketContextProvider>;
};

main.jsx:
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthContextProvider } from './context/AuthContext.jsx'
import { SocketContextProvider } from './context/SocketContext.jsx'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <SocketContextProvider>
          <App />
        </SocketContextProvider>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

Is there anything wrong with how I've implemented sockets?
